# How to define and find separatrix for a Hamiltonian system with more than one degree of freedom?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, non-linear-systems

For a Hamiltonian system with $n>1$ pairs of positions and momenta, how do we define a separatrix? Once defined, is there a theorem (involving action-angle variables (AAVs)) that we can use to find them?

For example, do we have separatrices when the frequencies (got from AAVs) are $0$? Or when the transformation ''constants of motion $\leftrightarrow$ actions'' is not invertible? Or when the transformation ''frequencies $\leftrightarrow$ actions'' is not invertible?

A reference to a book/article will be very convenient.

Comment: which definition do you currently have or use?

Comment: All I know is a layman's definition. Separatrix is a curve that divides the phase space on the basis of dynamics (rotation or libration). See Goldstein chapter 10.

Comment: A more constructive definition would be a phase curve that goes through a hyperbolic point.